# CSS pseudo selectors using first-child

Tags: css, css-selectors

I know I could do this easily by specifying an `id` but I want to practice with pseudo selectors.

I have two tables within a view. Using pseudo selectors:

- I want to grab the first table only.

  - within that first table's `<tbody>`

    - I want to grab the *first* `<tr>` and color all the text red.

My current implementation almost works.  The issue is that it does this styling for *every* table in the view.  I want this styling to happen *only* for the first table.

```css
tbody tr:first-child {
  color: red; 
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First Column</th>
      <th>Second Column</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td> T1 R1 Col 1</td>
      <td>This row should all be red</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>T1 R2 Col 1</td>
      <td>foobar</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First Column</th>
      <th>Second Column</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td> T2 R1 Col 1</td>
      <td>This row should NOT be red</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>T2 R2 Col 1</td>
      <td>foobar</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: `table:first-of-type tbody tr:first-child {color: red;}`. Here's a really good [**CSS reference**](http://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/) back at [codrops](http://tympanus.net/codrops/), written by a really good developer [Sara Soueidan](https://sarasoueidan.com/).

Comment: Thanks @RicardoRuiz, that really does look like a great resource!  I'll be using that to get better with selectors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take it a step further with the **pseudo selectors** since you already know you're targeting the first table and use `:first-of-type` which works similarly as `:nth-of-type(1)`

```css
table:first-of-type tbody tr:first-child {
  color: red; 
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First Column</th>
      <th>Second Column</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td> T1 R1 Col 1</td>
      <td>This row should all be red</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>T1 R2 Col 1</td>
      <td>foobar</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First Column</th>
      <th>Second Column</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td> T2 R1 Col 1</td>
      <td>This row should NOT be red</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>T2 R2 Col 1</td>
      <td>foobar</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 5):

Use another pseudo selector for the table:

```css
table:nth-of-type(1) tbody tr:first-child {
  color: red; 
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First Column</th>
      <th>Second Column</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td> T1 R1 Col 1</td>
      <td>This row should all be red</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>T1 R2 Col 1</td>
      <td>foobar</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First Column</th>
      <th>Second Column</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td> T2 R1 Col 1</td>
      <td>This row should NOT be red</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>T2 R2 Col 1</td>
      <td>foobar</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the tables in a container element and then apply this CSS

```css
.container > :first-child tr:first-child td:last-child {
  
  color: red;
  
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First Column</th>
      <th>Second Column</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td> T1 R1 Col 1</td>
      <td>This row should all be red</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>T1 R2 Col 1</td>
      <td>foobar</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First Column</th>
      <th>Second Column</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td> T2 R1 Col 1</td>
      <td>This row should NOT be red</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>T2 R2 Col 1</td>
      <td>foobar</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
  </div>
```

Note: This will apply the CSS to the first table in every .container element. Just specify an ID instead and it shouldn't be a problem

Comment: This answer does not work.  It is styling the first table's column as well which is not what I am trying to do here.

Comment: Easy fix. Is that better?